# Scipy won't find the optimum (simple cosine function)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to estimate the argument of a cosine function using the scipy optimizer (yes I am aware arc cos could be used, but I don't want to do that).

The code + a demonstration:

```
import numpy
import scipy

def solver(data):
    Z=numpy.zeros(len(data))
    a=0.003
    for i in range(len(data)):
        def minimizer(b):
            return numpy.abs(data[i]-numpy.cos(b))
        Z[i]=scipy.optimize.minimize(minimizer,a,bounds=[(0,numpy.pi)],method="L-BFGS-B").x[0]
    return Z

Y=numpy.zeros(100)
for i in range(100):
   Y[i]=numpy.cos(i/25)

solver(Y)
```

The result is not good, when the argument of the cos function reaches values above 2,  the estimation "skips over" the values and returns the maximum argument value instead.

```
array([0.        , 0.04      , 0.08      , 0.12      , 0.16      ,
       0.2       , 0.24      , 0.28      , 0.32      , 0.36      ,
       0.4       , 0.44      , 0.48      , 0.52      , 0.56      ,
       0.6       , 0.64      , 0.67999999, 0.72      , 0.75999999,
       0.8       , 0.83999999, 0.88      , 0.92      , 0.95999999,
       1.        , 1.04      , 1.08      , 1.12      , 1.16      ,
       1.2       , 1.24      , 1.28      , 1.32      , 1.36      ,
       1.4       , 1.44      , 1.48      , 1.52      , 1.56      ,
       1.6       , 1.64      , 1.68      , 1.72      , 1.76      ,
       1.8       , 1.84      , 1.88      , 1.91999999, 1.95999999,
       2.        , 2.04      , 3.14159265, 3.14159265, 3.14159265,
       3.14159265, 3.14159265, 3.14159265, 3.14159265, 3.14159265,...
```

What causes this phenomenon? Are there some other optimizers/ settings that could help with the issue?

Comment: Probably not the answer you are looking for, but preprocessing your inputs with `val %= 2 * numpy.pi` would probably do the trick.

Comment: @Dole Apart from that the code is not runnable - I hope that other people will understand better than me what you are trying to achieve and what your strategy is to achieve this.

Comment: @Mr. T Sorry, the array was not initialized. I would like to have an optimizer that can find the cosine argument. So if it is fed cos(2.4) it should returns 2.4. Instead as can be seen, it returns 3.14...

Comment: @Dole Not sure why it doesn't work but this is definitely a job for [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html). What you want to find is the root of the function `data[i] - np.cos(b)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that for the function (for example) `f = abs(cos(0.75*pi) - cos(z))` the gradient `f'` happens to vanish at `z = pi`, as can be seen from the following plot:

[image]

If you check the result the optimization procedure then you'll see that:

```
      fun: array([0.29289322])
 hess_inv: <1x1 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([0.])
  message: b'CONVERGENCE: NORM_OF_PROJECTED_GRADIENT_<=_PGTOL'
     nfev: 16
      nit: 2
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([3.14159265])
```

So the optimization procedure reached one of its convergence criteria. More detailed information about the criterion can be found at the [L-BFGS-B documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/optimize.minimize-lbfgsb.html). It says that

> gtol : float
>
> The iteration will stop when max{|proj g_i | i = 1, ..., n} <= gtol where pg_i is the i-th component of the projected gradient.

So it eventually reaches a point `z >= pi` which is then projected back to `z = pi` due to the constraint and at this point the gradient of the function is zero and hence it stops. You can observe that by registering a callback which prints the current parameter vector:

```
def new_callback():
    step = 1

    def callback(xk):
        nonlocal step
        print('Step #{}: xk = {}'.format(step, xk))
        step += 1

    return callback

scipy.optimize.minimize(..., callback=new_callback())
```

Which outputs:

```
Step #1: xk = [0.006]
Step #2: xk = [3.14159265]
```

So at the second step it hit `z >= pi` which is projected back to `z = pi`.

You can circumvent this problem by reducing the bounds to for example `bounds=[(0, 0.99*np.pi)]`. This will give you the expected result, however the method won't converge; you will see something like:

```
      fun: array([1.32930966e-09])
 hess_inv: <1x1 LbfgsInvHessProduct with dtype=float64>
      jac: array([0.44124484])
  message: b'ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH'
     nfev: 160
      nit: 6
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([2.35619449])
```

Note the message `ABNORMAL_TERMINATION_IN_LNSRCH`. This is due to the nature of `abs(x)` and the fact that its derivative has a discontinuity at `x = 0` (you can read more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39155976/3767239)).

## Alternative approach (finding the root)

For all the lines above we were trying to find a value `z` for which `cos(z) == cos(0.75*pi)` (or `abs(cos(z) - cos(0.75*pi)) < eps`). This problem is actually finding the root of the function `f = cos(z) - cos(0.75*pi)` where we can make use of the fact that `cos` is a continuous function. We need to set the boundaries `a, b` such that `f(a)*f(b) < 0` (i.e. they have opposite sign). For example using [`bisect` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html):

```
res = scipy.optimize.bisect(f, 0, np.pi)
```

Comment: I tried the bisect method. However, it complains that the signs are not different even though they are, is there a hack? The least squares worked well, but all the tolerances need to be maxed or the error grows rapidly.

Comment: @Dole If it complains about similar signs, then that's probably because they are indeed the same. Could you provide the definition of `f` as well as the case for which it doesn't work? Better triple check the call to `bisect` as well. What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 3):

Besides the general `minimize` method, SciPy has `minimize_scalar` specifically for 1-dimensional problems like here, and `least_squares` for minimizing a particular kind of functions that measure the difference between two quantities (such as the difference between `cos(b)` and `diff[i]` here). The latter performs well here, even without fine-tuning.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    Z[i] = scipy.optimize.least_squares(lambda b: data[i] - numpy.cos(b), a, bounds=(0, numpy.pi)).x[0]
```

The function passed to `least_squares` is the thing we'd like to be close to 0, without an absolute value on it. I'll add that a=0.003 seems a suboptimal choice for a starting point, being so close to the boundary; nonetheless it works.

Also, as `a_guest` already posted, a scalar root finding method should do the same thing while throwing fewer surprises here, given that we already have a nice bracketing interval [0, pi]. Bisection is reliable but slow; [Brent's method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding) is what I'd probably use.

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    Z[i] = scipy.optimize.brentq(lambda b: data[i] - numpy.cos(b), 0, numpy.pi)
```